# How do I fix (idle) that shows up in the Chrome JavaScript Profiler?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I have a JavaScript script in an Angular page that executes a promise chain as follows:

```
foo().then(() => {
    console.profile("foo1");
    ...
    return foo1();
}).then(() => {
    console.profileEnd("foo1");
    console.profile("foo2");
    ...
    return foo2();
}).then(() => {
    console.profileEnd("foo2");
    console.profile("foo3");
    ...
    return foo3();
})
...
```

I use `console.profile` to find out which part of the promise chain takes so much time to execute. What I noticed is that one of the profilers (in my case `foo6`) has a 350ms idle time. What is a good approach to find out why it is not executing anything although the promise chain has still not finished?

[image: console.time(]

Comment: What kind of work is `foo6` doing? Is there any chance it's making a network request or using some other resource that would cause it to be idle?

Comment: Why are you using promises and not Observables?

Comment: Ideal time mean resource was not utilized during that timeframe.. 

Probably it can happen because of the below reasons:
1. It was waiting for another process to get executed
2. if it is a different domain endpoint, your client is waiting for a handshake for that specific endpoint
3. Probably check on the number of new connections which is already established and being used. Please check any max connections limit is there or not also

Comment: not sure it would help, but I would convert the promise chain to an async/await method, e.g. `await foo(); console.profile("foo1"); ... await foo1(); console.profileEnd("foo1"); console.profile("foo2"); ... await foo2();...`

Comment: i am thinking same way with @kylejrp. for the foo6 function, main thread goes idle and waits before ready.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply!! Unfortunately it doesn't do any external network request. But I reinstalled all node modules and updated a few others and the issue seems to be gone...magically. :-/